# wiring size to storage shed

Tags: wiring

Florida..Have storage shed approx. 60' from house. Have a gfci box on front porch, was planning on connecting to box for pwr supply w 14 Ga.. planning on wire in elect. conduit, wire run will be about 75'. lighting is ( 4) 500 watt shop lights ( not on at same time), maybe two at same time.

Comment: I don't see a question up there. Please edit to clarify what you're asking. Will you ever want to run power tools off the circuit?

Comment: You're not allowed to use secret only-I-know tricks to avert overloads, because you will not be the only person using this space. The next owner, a guest or an emergency responder won't know the "turn on only 2 lights" trick, and will overload the circuit.  i get trying to save money on wire, but I'd look at a different approach like efficient lighting.  An ebay cheapie 50W LED flood light is a good swap for a 500W halogen.  And when you bang into it, it won't blow the bulb.  fluorescent tube lights are also cheap, efficient and very bright.

Answer (score 1):

With just 1000w total 14 awg the voltage drop would be 2.85% at 75'. So you could do it with 14awg. 2000w the wire size would be 10awg. For some reason I was thinking 1000w or 2 lights. Going to LED may get you the needed light and not have to go to the larger wire.

Comment: Seems like one would need to assume that the lights *could* all be on at the same time. Would that change anything?

Comment: Wow I thought it said 2,  500w lights that's why I put 1000w, + , I would upsize and run direct from the panel with a MWBC at a minum.